# Return a list from a list, where every column of every data frame is of type character

Tags: r, list, filter

This is the list we can work with:

```
list1 <- list(L1 = c(a = "abc", b = "bca"),
              L2 = c(a = 1, b = 2))
```

In this case i need a list, that only contains lists that meet the condition, so L1.
This is how i can check it by hand, but i dont know how to go further.

```
class(list1[[1]][[1]])
class(list1[[1]][[2]])
class(list1[[2]][[1]])
class(list1[[2]][[2]])
```

Comment: Even if you had a vector like `L1 = c(a = "abc", b = 1)`, both elements would be character since integers would be coerced into strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for `is.character` in an `sapply` and subset the list.

```
list1[sapply(list1, is.character)]
# $L1
#    a     b 
# "abc" "bca"
```

Comment: Ah, i see where the problem is now. In my original list are not more lists, but tibbles. I guess thats why i dont get anything back. How to do it then? change the tibbles to lists or is there another way?

Comment: @Dutschke You could try `rapply(list1, function(x) x[is.character(x)])`, however I suggest asking a new question with an example that better resembles your actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Filter` from `base R`

```
Filter(is.character, list1)
```